# How parse with JavaScriptSeiralizer this JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

How parse with  JavaScriptSeiralizer this JSON?

```
    response: {
    count: 149,
    items: [{
    id: 318869260,
    album_id: -7,
    owner_id: 1,
    sizes: [{
    src: 'http://cs7003.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/8512/Lz9Om2nH7ws.jpg',
    width: 68,
    height: 75,
    type: 's'
    }, {
    src: 'http://cs7003.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/8513/eTw2eVnJGZY.jpg',
    width: 118,
    height: 130,
    type: 'm'
    }, {
    src: 'http://cs7003.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/8514/xOgTUSphy0g.jpg',
    width: 549,
    height: 604,
    type: 'x'
    }, {
    src: 'http://cs7003.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/8515/AqjVSivDR7U.jpg',
    width: 609,
    height: 670,
    type: 'y'
    }, {
    src: 'http://cs7003.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/8516/n-kCiDpG3Ck.jpg',
    width: 130,
    height: 143,
    type: 'o'
    }, {
    src: 'http://cs7003.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/8517/9CcHWimcZ5g.jpg',
    width: 200,
    height: 220,
    type: 'p'
    }, {
    src: 'http://cs7003.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/8518/zQSPjAWRk2Y.jpg',
    width: 320,
    height: 352,
    type: 'q'
    }, {
    src: 'http://cs7003.vk.me/c540101/v540101001/8519/9YzsZ1OF1Sc.jpg',
    width: 510,
    height: 561,
    type: 'r'
    }],
    text: '',
    date: 1388437503,
    likes: {
    user_likes: 0,
    count: 11553
    }
    }]
    }
```

How make class for parsing?

1 Class

```
Class Users
{
public List<Photo> response { get; set; }
}
```

2 Class

```
class Photo
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public long abum_id { get; set; }
        public long owner_id { get; set; }
        public string photo_75 { get; set; }
        public string photo_130 { get; set; }
        public string photo_604 { get; set; }
        public string photo_807 { get; set; }
        public string photo_1280 { get; set; }
        public string photo_2560 { get; set; }
        public long width { get; set; }
        public long height { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public long date { get; set; }
        public long post_id { get; set; }

    }
```

Deserialization:

```
var idList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Users>(getResponseFriend);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just past the json in http://json2csharp.com/

classes generated:

```
public class Size
{
    public string src { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Likes
{
    public int user_likes { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int album_id { get; set; }
    public int owner_id { get; set; }
    public List<Size> sizes { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public Likes likes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```